# PHP while loop array return

Tags: php, class, pdo, while-loop

I try to implement something like:

```
$data = my_obj::get_rows();
```

`$data` is now a **PDO Statement**,

`my_obj` is my class ( i have one for every db table ), implements __set and __get magic

`get_rows()` is a static method that return a PDO Statement.

Now i want convert $data to an `my_obj` instance, so I can have access to class method, something like :

```
 while( $d = my_obj::inject( $data ) ){
         $d->my_method();
 }
```

Now, i try to write my `::inject` static method:

```
     static function inject($pdo_statement) {

        $data = $pdo_statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //and now?

    }
```

Can anyone help to solve this method?

Comment: it really isn't clear what you are trying to do and what your code is currently doing from the examples you've provided. is my_obj a data model (it seems more like a mapper)?

Comment: my_obj is a mapper that extends my PDO class wrapper.